Map Keys with value of Subkeys in jq
I try to reformat the output of the sensors command:
sensors -j ftsteutates-i2c-0-73
{
   "ftsteutates-i2c-0-73":{
      "Adapter": "SMBus I801 adapter at efa0",
      "VCC 3.3V":{
         "in0_input": 3.331
      },
      "3.3V AUX":{
         "in1_input": 3.359
      },
      "V_IN (12V)":{
         "in2_input": 12.012
      },
      "VBAT 3.0V":{
         "in3_input": 2.692
      },
      "CPU":{
         "fan1_input": 660.000,
         "fan1_alarm": 0.000,
         "fan1_fault": 0.000
      },
      "Chassis":{
         "fan3_input": 1200.000,
         "fan3_alarm": 0.000,
         "fan3_fault": 0.000
      },
      "CPU":{
         "temp1_input": 51.000,
         "temp1_alarm": 0.000,
         "temp1_fault": 0.000
      },
      "Ambient":{
         "temp2_input": 44.000,
         "temp2_alarm": 0.000,
         "temp2_fault": 0.000
      },
      "Core":{
         "temp3_input": 54.000,
         "temp3_alarm": 0.000,
         "temp3_fault": 0.000
      },
      "Memory":{
         "temp4_input": 42.000,
         "temp4_alarm": 0.000,
         "temp4_fault": 0.000
      },
      "PCH":{
         "temp5_input": 54.000,
         "temp5_alarm": 0.000,
         "temp5_fault": 0.000
      },
      "Graphics":{
         "temp6_input": 40.000,
         "temp6_alarm": 0.000,
         "temp6_fault": 0.000
      }
   }
}

What I am expecting is:
sensors -j ftsteutates-i2c-0-73 | jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | del(."Adapter") | ???' 
{
  "VCC 3.3V": 3.331,
  "3.3V AUX": 3.359,
  "V_IN (12V)": 12.012,
  "VBAT 3.0V": 2.692,
  "CPU": 51.000,
  "Chassis": 1200.000,
  "Ambient": 44.000,
  "Core": 54.000,
  "Memory": 42.000,
  "PCH": 54.000,
  "Graphics": 40.000
}

But I cant figure out how to Map the values of the subkeys and also delete the *_alarm and *_fault subkeys or select just the first subkey which is always the *_input key.
EDIT:
I found, that the temp and fan values from CPU get joined, which need to be keeped.
Maybe it is possible to match the part of the subkey name in/fan/temp and join it together in the output name like:
sensors -j ftsteutates-i2c-0-73 | jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | del(."Adapter") | ???' 
{
  "VCC 3.3V_in": 3.331,
  "3.3V AUX_in": 3.359,
  "V_IN (12V)_in": 12.012,
  "VBAT 3.0V_in": 2.692,
  "CPU_fan": 51.000,
  "Chassis_fan": 1200.000,
  "Ambient_temp": 44.000,
  "Core_temp": 54.000,
  "Memory_temp": 42.000,
  "PCH_temp": 54.000,
  "Graphics_temp": 40.000
}

Somehow like (dosnt work)
sensors -j ftsteutates-i2c-0-73 | jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | del(."Adapter") | with_entries(.key |= gsub(" "; "_") | .value |= with_entries(select(.key | endswith("_input")) | .key |= gsub("_input"; "_in") | .key |= gsub("temp"; "_temp") | .key |= gsub("fan"; "_fan"))) | with_entries(.value |= if type == "object" then .[] else . end)'

or
sensors -j ftsteutates-i2c-0-73 | jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | del(."Adapter") | with_entries(.value |= if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.key | endswith("_input")) | .key |= gsub("_input"; "_in") | .key |= gsub("temp"; "_temp") | .key |= gsub("fan"; "_fan")) else . end) | with_entries(.value |= if type == "object" then .[] else . end)'


Note that this sample contains two CPU fields. jq (as most JSON processors) collapses duplcate keys. You won't get JSON output from jq with duplicate keys.

Here's another way using the error suppression operator ? (with jq 1.7+):
jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | .[] |= (.[keys[] | select(endswith("_input"))])?'

Demo
For older versions, just add another types filter for objects (with jq 1.6+):
jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | .[] |= (objects | .[keys[] | select(endswith("_input"))])'

Demo
Not recommended, but if the field ending with _input is always encoded as the first one, you could even shorten this with jq 1.7+ to:
jq '."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73" | .[] |= .[]?'   # or .[] |= objects[]

Demo
Result (due to its type, the Adapter field was deleted implicitly):
{
  "VCC 3.3V": 3.331,
  "3.3V AUX": 3.359,
  "V_IN (12V)": 12.012,
  "VBAT 3.0V": 2.692,
  "CPU": 51.000,
  "Chassis": 1200.000,
  "Ambient": 44.000,
  "Core": 54.000,
  "Memory": 42.000,
  "PCH": 54.000,
  "Graphics": 40.000
}



EDIT: I found, that the temp and fan values from CPU get joined, which need to be keeped.
Maybe it is possible to match the part of the subkey name in/fan/temp and join it together in the output name

You'd need to --stream the input at invocation in order to process broken-down parts individually, before they are collapsed in a superordinate structure.
Here's one way using just from_entries on a prepared array:
jq --stream -n '
  [inputs | select(.[0][0] == "ftsteutates-i2c-0-73") | {
    key: "\(.[0][1])_\(.[0][2] | strings | scan("^(.*)\\d+_input$")[0])", 
    value: .[1] | values
  }] | from_entries
'

Here's another one using reduce to successively build up the output:
jq --stream -n '
  reduce (inputs | select(has(1))) as [$path, $val]
    (.; setpath($path | .[1:] |= [join("_")]; $val))
  | ."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73"
  | with_entries(.key = (.key | scan("^(.*)\\d+_input$")[0]))
'

Result:
{
  "VCC 3.3V_in": 3.331,
  "3.3V AUX_in": 3.359,
  "V_IN (12V)_in": 12.012,
  "VBAT 3.0V_in": 2.692,
  "CPU_fan": 660.000,
  "Chassis_fan": 1200.000,
  "CPU_temp": 51.000,
  "Ambient_temp": 44.000,
  "Core_temp": 54.000,
  "Memory_temp": 42.000,
  "PCH_temp": 54.000,
  "Graphics_temp": 40.000
}


I found one problem: the CPU temp and fan values are getting joined and so one gets kicket.... I will update my question

@Thomas jq (as most JSON processors) collapses duplcate keys. You won't get JSON output from jq with duplicate keys.

my idea is, that I cut a part of the subkey name (like in/fan/temp - the beginning till the number) into the name of the key. So the keys stays uniq

Nice, that works!

A simple solution using jq:
.["ftsteutates-i2c-0-73"] | map_values(objects | .[(keys[] | select(endswith("_input")))])

How it works:
.["ftsteutates-i2c-0-73"].     # extract the interesting object
| map_values(                  # process its values, preserve the keys association
    objects                    # process only the values that are object (ignore "Adapter")
    | .[                              # extract only some properties of these objects
        keys[] |                      # choose the keys...
        select(endswith("_input"))    # ...ending in "_input"
      ]                               # yield the values of the chosen keys
  )

See it online.
h3. Remarks

if multiple keys ending in _input are present in an object, the value associated to the last one is returned;
the sample data contains the key CPU two times;
depending on the JSON implementation, this can be reported as invalid
JSON or one of the keys is ignored (usually the last occurrence
overwrites any previous occurrences); this is also how jq works.


I updated my question because of the CPU problem....

I got the right answer:
sensors -j ftsteutates-i2c-0-73 | jq '
  ."ftsteutates-i2c-0-73"
  | del(."Adapter")
  | with_entries(.value |= 
      if type == "object" 
      then with_entries(select(.key
                               | endswith("_input")))
      | .[] 
      else . end)'

This command does the following:
with_entries(.value |= if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.key | endswith("_input"))) | .[] else . end): 

Iterates over each key-value pair, and if the value is an object, it selects the entries where the key ends with _input and then extracts the value.
This give me the desired output.
https://jqplay.org/s/KLkFpP0Q2yN3f9j
